# Finding the limit of the sequence: $ x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} ?$

Tags: calculus

We have a sequence defined as the following: 
$ x_n = {\lim_{p \to \infty}[\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}(1+\frac{k}{p})^{1/n}]^{n}}\ $
 I want to find the limit:  $ x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} ?$  . I tried my best to find a way to compute it, but I couldn't. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ \lim_{p\to\infty}\frac 1 p \sum_{k=1}^p \left(1+\frac k p\right)^{1/n} = \int_1^2 (1+x)^{1/n} dx = \frac{n}{n+1}\left(3^{\frac{n+1} n} - 2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)$$ since the left-hand side is a limit of Riemann sums with mesh size approaching $0$. Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{n}{n+1}\left(3^{\frac{n+1} n} - 2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)\right]^n = L.$$

We apply the usual trick of taking the natural log of the limit:

$$ \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} n \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) + n\ln\left( 3^{\frac{n+1} n} - 2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right).$$ Applying L'Hospital's rule for each of the terms in the above limit gives us that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = -1 $$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln\left( 3^{\frac{n+1} n} - 2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right) = 3\ln 3 - 2\ln2.$$

Thus
$$ \ln L = -1 + 3\ln3 - 2 \ln 2 $$
and exponentiating both sides gives
$$ L = \frac{27}{4e},$$ which is the the limit of $x_n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much Trevor.

Comment: excuse me how did you get 3ln3 -2ln2?

Comment: @Kamal The $3\ln3 - 2 \ln 2$ comes from applying L'Hospital's rule to $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln\left( 3^{\frac{n+1} n} - 2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)$. It will help to rewrite the limit as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(3^{1+1/x} - 2^{1+1/x}) }{1/x}. $$ The details are messy, but it's a fairly straight-forward calculation.

Comment: Thank you, I did the same thing. I will redo the calculations.